# installedApps return custom application id for user even it is not installed for him

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Below request returns custom application (externalId 068661a0-624f-4fcd-a4e8-70dd5738ec99) which is not installed for user (03bc2854-da85-49d4-a6cb-0f372170e3a4) in query (another user only installed it):

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/03bc2854-da85-49d4-a6cb-0f372170e3a4/teamwork/installedApps?$expand=teamsApp,teamsAppDefinition&$filter=teamsApp/externalId+eq+'068661a0-624f-4fcd-a4e8-70dd5738ec99'](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/03bc2854-da85-49d4-a6cb-0f372170e3a4/teamwork/installedApps?$expand=teamsApp,teamsAppDefinition&$filter=teamsApp/externalId+eq+%27068661a0-624f-4fcd-a4e8-70dd5738ec99%27)

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('03bc2854-da85-49d4-a6cb-0f372170e3a4')/teamwork/installedApps(teamsApp(),teamsAppDefinition())",
"@odata.count": 1,
"@microsoft.graph.tips": "Use $select to choose only the properties your app needs, as this can lead to performance improvements. For example: GET users('<03bc2854-da85-49d4-a6cb-0f372170e3a4>')/teamwork/installedApps?$select=consentedPermissionSet,grantedResourceSpecificApplicationPermissions",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "MDNiYzI4NTQtZGE4NS00OWQ0LWE2Y2ItMGYzNzIxNzBlM2E0IyNmMWMxYWU1Ny1mMmU3LTQyNWItOWQ4MS1mMDA5ZmJhMTVlNTU=",
        "consentedPermissionSet": null,
        "teamsApp": {
            "id": "f1c1ae57-f2e7-425b-9d81-f009fba15e55",
            "externalId": "068661a0-624f-4fcd-a4e8-70dd5738ec99",
            "displayName": "Activity feed broadcast",
            "distributionMethod": "organization"
        },
        "teamsAppDefinition": {
            "id": "ZjFjMWFlNTctZjJlNy00MjViLTlkODEtZjAwOWZiYTE1ZTU1IyMxLjAuMCMjUHVibGlzaGVk",
            "teamsAppId": "f1c1ae57-f2e7-425b-9d81-f009fba15e55",
            "azureADAppId": "068661a0-624f-4fcd-a4e8-70dd5738ec99",
            "displayName": "Activity feed broadcast",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "requiredResourceSpecificApplicationPermissions": [],
            "publishingState": "published",
            "shortdescription": "Activity feed notification to notify any message to the organisation",
            "description": "Activity feed notification to notify any message to all members of the organisation.",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": null,
            "allowedInstallationScopes": "personal",
            "serializedInternalDefinition": null,
            "createdBy": null,
            "authorization": {
                "requiredPermissionSet": {
                    "resourceSpecificPermissions": []
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

The login to Graph explorer done by tenant' admin user. The same response received for user which installed app for him. I expect that user who is not installed custom Teams app should get zero in response.

Comment: Could you please verify once if the custom app is uninstalled for the user? If app is uninstalled properly, we won't get the app details in response.

Comment: the problem is that this custom app was never installed for user - I mean user did not install it. Maybe exist a way to install it on-behalf of user? so all user got this application automatically installed? I just pickup some of lab users that event never logged into teams and they have this app installed, how it can be?

Comment: It looks like you have installed https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed-broadcast/csharp sample. Please note that this sample gets installed for everyone in tenant for broadcasting the notification. That is the reason you are getting this app as installed even if the user has never logged in.

Comment: what makes application, to be installed automatically for everyone in tenant? Could you please explain. I do not see anything special in manifest.json.

Comment: This is the for installing app to all user - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/8535a89765319f3940e2a4eac7a9eb517a980211/samples/graph-activity-feed-broadcast/csharp/ActivityFeedBroadcast/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L132

Comment: this piece of code runs when you make a broadcast to test application, but how it deployed automatically for all users?

Comment: Could you please confirm if the app got installed for other users without even testing the application?

Comment: I do not have option to login to other users, but below query from teams sample:

 var installedApp = await graphClient.Users[users.Id].Teamwork.InstalledApps
                                             .Request()
                                             .Expand("teamsApp")
                                             .GetAsync();

returns for each user that application installed

Comment: Did you test the application with the admin account?